# Not able to Enable CORS header setting in my apache server

Tags: apache, cors, header

I am unable to enable CORS header for my apache server. I am not able to see Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response. httpd.conf is given below. Please provide support how to enable it first and how to cross check/verify whether it is actually enabled or not. I have tried to verify CORS was enabled or not using network tab of chrome browser in developer tools section but in server response I am not able to see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin tag.

> ```
> Define CERT_DIR "C:/Apache24/conf/"
> SetEnv CERT_DIR ${CERT_DIR}
>
> # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
> # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
> # See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
> # In particular, see 
> # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
> # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
>
> ServerRoot "c:/Apache24"
>
> #
> # Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
> # for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
> #
> # Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
> # mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
> # other reason.
> #
> # Mutex default:logs
>
> #
> # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
> # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
> # directive.
> #
> # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
> # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
> #
> #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
> Listen 80
>
> #
> # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
> #
> # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
> # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
> # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
> # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
> # to be loaded here.
> #
> # Example:
> # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
> #
> LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
> LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
> LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
> LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
> LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
> LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
> #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
> #LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
> #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
> LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
> #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
> #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
> LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
> #LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
> #LoadModule authnz_fcgi_module modules/mod_authnz_fcgi.so
> #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
> LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
> #LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
> #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
> LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
> LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
> #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
> LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
> LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
> #LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
> #LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
> #LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
> #LoadModule cache_socache_module modules/mod_cache_socache.so
> #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
> LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
> #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
> #LoadModule data_module modules/mod_data.so
> #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
> #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
> #LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
> #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
> #LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
> LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
> #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
> LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
> #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
> #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
> #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
> #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
> #LoadModule http2_module modules/mod_http2.so
> LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
> #LoadModule heartbeat_module modules/mod_heartbeat.so
> #LoadModule heartmonitor_module modules/mod_heartmonitor.so
> #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
> #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
> LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
> #LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
> LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
> #LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
> #LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
> #LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
> #LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
> #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
> #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
> LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
> #LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
> #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
> #LoadModule lua_module modules/mod_lua.so
> #LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so
> LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
> #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
> LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
> #LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
> #LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
> #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
> #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
> #LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
> #LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
> #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
> #LoadModule proxy_html_module modules/mod_proxy_html.so
> #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
> #LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
> #LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
> #LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
> #LoadModule reflector_module modules/mod_reflector.so
> #LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
> #LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
> #LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
> #LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
> #LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
> #LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
> #LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
> #LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
> LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
> #LoadModule slotmem_plain_module modules/mod_slotmem_plain.so
> #LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
> LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
> #LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
> LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
> #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
> LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
> #LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
> #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
> #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
> #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
> #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
> #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
> #LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
> #LoadModule watchdog_module modules/mod_watchdog.so
> #LoadModule xml2enc_module modules/mod_xml2enc.so
>
> ### PHP ###
> LoadModule php7_module "C:/PHP/php7apache2_4.dll"
> AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
> PHPIniDir "C:/PHP"
>
> <IfModule unixd_module>
> #
> # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
> # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
> #
> # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
> # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
> # running httpd, as with most system services.
> #
> User daemon
> Group daemon
>
> </IfModule>
>
> # 'Main' server configuration
> #
> # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
> # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
> # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
> # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
> #
> # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
> # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
> # virtual host being defined.
> #
>
> #
> # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
> # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
> # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
> #
> ServerAdmin admin@example.com
>
> #
> # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
> # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
> # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
> #
> # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
> #
> ServerName 192.168.1.21:80
>
> #
> # Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
> # explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
> # <Directory> blocks below.
> #
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride none
>     Require all denied
> </Directory>
>
> #
> # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
> # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
> # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
> # below.
> #
>
> #
> # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
> # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
> # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
> #
> DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/htdocs"
> <Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
>     #
>     # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
>     # or any combination of:
>     #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
>     #
>     # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
>     # doesn't give it to you.
>     #
>     # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
>     # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
>     # for more information.
>     #
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>
>     #
>     # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
>     # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
>     #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
>     #
>     AllowOverride None
>
>     #
>     # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
>     #
> <IfModule mod_headers.so>
>    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
>    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
>    #"Origin,Content-Type,Authorization,X-Requested-With"
>    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
>    #Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Content-Security-Policy, Location"
>    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "600"
>    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
> </IfModule>
>
>     Require all granted
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteRule "^swordfish/lock/certificates/current(.*)$" "/cert.php$1" [L]
>     RewriteRule "^api/certificates/devices/current(.*)$" "/echo_cert.php" [L]
>     RewriteRule "^swordfish/lock/Config" "/config.php" [L]
>     RewriteRule "^swordfish/lock/audit" "/audit.php" [L]
>     RewriteRule "^swordfish/lock/alert" "/alert.php" [L]
> </Directory>
>
> #
> # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
> # is requested.
> #
> <IfModule dir_module>
>     DirectoryIndex index.html
> </IfModule>
>
> #
> # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
> # viewed by Web clients. 
> #
> <Files ".ht*">
>     Require all denied
> </Files>
>
> #
> # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
> # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
> # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
> # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
> # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
> #
> ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
>
> #
> # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
> # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
> # alert, emerg.
> #
> LogLevel debug
>
> <IfModule log_config_module>
>     #
>     # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
>     # a CustomLog directive (see below).
>     #
>     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
>     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
>
>     <IfModule logio_module>
>       # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
>       LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
>     </IfModule>
>
>     #
>     # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
>     # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
>     # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
>     # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
>     # logged therein and *not* in this file.
>     #
>     CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
>
>     #
>     # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
>     # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
>     #
>     #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
> </IfModule>
>
> <IfModule alias_module>
>     #
>     # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
>     # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
>     # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
>     # Example:
>     # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar
>
>     #
>     # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
>     # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
>     # Example:
>     # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
>     #
>     # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
>     # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
>     # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
>     # the filesystem path.
>
>     #
>     # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
>     # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
>     # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
>     # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
>     # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
>     # directives as to Alias.
>     #
>     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin/"
>
> </IfModule>
>
> <IfModule cgid_module>
>     #
>     # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
>     # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
>     #
>     #Scriptsock cgisock
> </IfModule>
>
> #
> # "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
> # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
> #
> <Directory "c:/Apache24/cgi-bin">
>     AllowOverride None
>     Options None
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <IfModule mime_module>
>     #
>     # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
>     # filename extension to MIME-type.
>     #
>     TypesConfig conf/mime.types
>
>     #
>     # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
>     # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
>     #
>     #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
>     #
>     # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
>     # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
>     #
>     #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
>     #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
>     #
>     # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
>     # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
>     #
>     AddType application/x-compress .Z
>     AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
>
>     #
>     # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
>     # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
>     # or added with the Action directive (see below)
>     #
>     # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
>     # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
>     #
>     #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
>
>     # For type maps (negotiated resources):
>     #AddHandler type-map var
>
>     #
>     # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
>     #
>     # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
>     # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
>     #
>     #AddType text/html .shtml
>     #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
> </IfModule>
>
> #
> # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
> # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
> # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
> #
> #MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
>
> #
> # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
> # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
> #
> # Some examples:
> #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
> #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
> #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
> #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
> #
>
> #
> # MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
> # returning the entire resource, or one of the special
> # values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
> # Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
> #MaxRanges unlimited
>
> #
> # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
> # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
> # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
> # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
> # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
> # broken on your system.
> # Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
> #
> #EnableMMAP off
> #EnableSendfile on
>
> # Supplemental configuration
> #
> # The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
> # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
> # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
> # necessary.
>
> # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
>
> # Multi-language error messages
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
>
> # Fancy directory listings
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
>
> # Language settings
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf
>
> # User home directories
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
>
> # Real-time info on requests and configuration
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf
>
> # Virtual hosts
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
>
> # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf
>
> # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf
>
> # Various default settings
> #Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
>
> # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
> <IfModule proxy_html_module>
> Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
> </IfModule>
>
> # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
> Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
> #
> # Note: The following must must be present to support
> #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
> #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
> #
> <IfModule ssl_module>
> SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
> SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
> </IfModule>
> ```